# Which episodes of Sailor Moon Crystal are Ittou Asanuma in?

Tags: sailor-moon

I believe that Ittou Asanuma's first appearance in *Sailor Moon Crystal* is in episode 15 when Makoto introduces him to Usagi and friends, that he does not appear in episode 16, and that his famous scene with Makoto from the manga is in episode 17. Is he in any other episodes, or did he only appear in those two 2 episodes?

[image: Kino Makoto and Ittou Asanuma]

Comment: Given that I don't recall him in the first half of the show (as you've pretty much stated here) back when I was still following the anime, I'll see if I find much whenever I get back to watching it again, if no one else comes up with anything.

Answer (score 2):

I do not recall Asanuma appearing in the first half of the show. It's of course possible he might have appeared earlier as a background object, similar to how the Curtis couple in *Fullmetal Alchemist* shows up in the background when Winry arrives in Central before they are formally introduced, but there are assuredly no *explicit* appearances up until episode 15. (If he did show up before then, it would be unsurprising for me -- as someone not *that* invested into *Sailor Moon* -- to have missed it, since I would not have known of Asanuma before episode 15.)

Thus:

- Episodes 1-14: no explicit appearances
- Episode 15: Makoto introduces Asanuma
- Episode 16: no appearance except in the preview for 17.
- Episode 17: Asanuma asks Makoto about her identity and tells her he wants to protect her.
- Episode 18: Asanuma is briefly shown standing in front of a building right before the half-way mark, thinking of Makoto, and then at the fortune-telling meeting being brainwashed along with some other characters (Naru-chan, Sarashina from Rei's school).
- Episode 19-25: no appearance: apart from two brief instances where Usagi and some of her friends return to the 20th century, these episodes are entirely set in the 30th century.
- Episode 26: short appearance in a still towards the end, after characters return to earth.

Comment: thank you so much for this helpful answer! Looking forward to selecting it as correct as soon as you update with the remaining episodes. I love the classic magical girl shows but _Sailor Moon Crystal_ is so poorly-written and poorly-animated that though I tried, I couldn't sit through the whole thing. But I love Asanuma in the manga so I want to watch just the episodes that he's in since he finally got animated (in the classic anime, he only had 1 cameo of knocking on a door). If you're looking for more interesting themes in magical series, try ones from the mid-90s and earlier. (^_~)

Comment: @seijitsu: that makes sense; I was wondering about the motivation for the question. I tend to find a lot of magical girl shows too episodic and/or focused on, well, stereotypically "girly" things. (Maybe I'm also too old for _Pretty Cute_ /etc., but I have less problems sitting through _Chibi Maruko-chan_ or _Doraemon_ episodes, and I kind of enjoy watching the live-action _Ultraman_ out of nostalgia, despite never having seriously seen it growing up.) I do rather like _Revolutionary Girl Utena_ though, but it lacks some of the qualities I've grown to expect from "magical girl" shows.

Comment: @seijitsu: final update done!